# How can I trigger a javascript Facebook authentication dialog box on an anchor tag?

Tags: ajax, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a simple rating system that logged in users can just click and it updates asynchronously.

However, I still want non-logged in users to see the rating mechanism (let's say a simple "up" arrow) but trigger the Facebook authentication popup when they click the link.

Can you help?  I have the regular fb:login button working just fine.  But how can I trigger this action on a regular anchor tag (in addition to the fb:login button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the FB.login method
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

You can bind this to the button click for non logged in users, on the callback you can register the original rating action or refresh the page.